# Compare Numbers using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to compare right numbers and left numbers using javascript, this is my input sample

```
290|0
290|0
290|2902
250|0
250|0
0|0
0|1299.95
0|1299.95
250|0
290|0
290|0
290|22
32|1299.95
0|0
```

then the results are greater numbers:

```
290
290
2902
250
250
0
1299.95
1299.95
250
290
290
290
1299.95
0
```

Please help!

Comment: if right_number == left_number

Comment: So, you need to compare numbers, what is your question? `290|0` is not a datatype in JS, what kind of data you have? What is the type of results you need?

Comment: Math.max(num1,num2); ???

Comment: Please try reading others' questions to help u improve the quality of ur questions

Comment: `Please help!` - there's many javascript tutorials online, I'd start with an introduction level one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do it the long way:-

```
var input = '290|0\n\
290|0\n\
290|2902\n\
250|0\n\
250|0\n\
0|0\n\
0|1299.95\n\
0|1299.95\n\
250|0\n\
290|0\n\
290|0\n\
290|22\n\
32|1299.95\n\
0|0'

var rows = input.split( '\n' )
var output = [ ]

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
    var row = rows[i]
    var parts = row.split( '|' )
    if ( 1*parts[0] > 1*parts[1] ) 
        output.push( parts[0] )
    else
        output.push( parts[1] )
}
output = '\n'.join( output )
```

Comment: Hi @Fred i have a problem, `32|1299` results `32` and `290|1299.95` results `290` https://jsfiddle.net/1g0q0p9q/

Comment: You are correct @Ph! I was comparing the strings and '3' is > '1'. I have edited my answer to force numeric instead of string comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You need `Math.Max()` 
It will return the biggest number as requested
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_max.asp